# How to convert Map to Java.util.Properties?

Tags: java, scala

Is there a way to convert from `Map` to `java.util.Properties`?

For example, the following `Map` I would like to convert into `java.util.Properties`:

```
Map("x" -> 24, "y" -> 25, "z" -> 26)
```

Comment: Create a Properties object, iterate over the Map entries and set a property in the Properties object for each Map entry. I don't know scala, maybe it can be a one-liner there.

Comment: A quick google search for the [**javadoc**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#putAll-java.util.Map-) show the `addAll` method that adds all values in a **Java** `Map` to the properties. And another quick [google search ](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/conversions-between-java-and-scala-collections.html) shows how to convert a **Scala** `Map` into a **Java** one. Leading to `val p = new Properties(); p.addAll(m.asJava)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the following

```
import java.util.Properties
val m = Map("x" -> 24, "y" -> 25, "z" -> 26)
val properties = new Properties
m.foreach { case (key, value) => properties.setProperty(key, value.toString) }
properties
```

which should output

```
res1: java.util.Properties = {x=24, z=26, y=25}
```

Answer (score 9):

You could use `putAll` from `Properties`, but it expects Java's map, so you'd also need to do the conversion:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._ 

val m = Map("x" -> 24, "y" -> 25, "z" -> 26)
val properties = new Properties()
properties.putAll(m.mapValues(_.toString).asJava)
```

As **MarioGalic** noticed in comment all values stored in properties should be Strings (even though you could theoretically store any object). From docs:

> Because Properties inherits from Hashtable, the put and putAll methods can be applied to a Properties object. Their use is strongly discouraged as they allow the caller to insert entries whose keys or values are not Strings. The setProperty method should be used instead. If the store or save method is called on a "compromised" Properties object that contains a non-String key or value, the call will fail. Similarly, the call to the propertyNames or list method will fail if it is called on a "compromised" Properties object that contains a non-String key.

Because of that, you'd probably need to call `mapValues(_.toString)`:

```
properties.putAll(m.mapValues(_.toString).asJava)
```

Comment: Don't you just love java's inheritance is class hierarchy?

Comment: Pre-generic Java was a lot of fun ;)

Comment: Post-generic isn't all that much better actually.